# Help changing OSX Eclipse Java Heap allocation

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, memory, heap-memory

I need to increase the heap allocation but I think I am missing a step, I follow this instructions http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini but the ini file is different from mine, this is what I get

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1536m
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

I change line **-Xmx1536m** but still get the out of memory problem, any ideas what else I need to setup? I have the latest 64bit Eclipse IDE and running on OSX 10.6.7

Thanks

Comment: Are you running out of memory with Eclipse or with an application you're running in Eclipse? Typically Eclipse doesn't need 1536m.

Comment: Yes an application, forgot to point that out

Comment: Ah ok. What you're doing is specifying the amount of memory for Eclipse itself. For an application see my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your comments you clarified that you're trying to increase the memory for an application you're running in Eclipse. What you've been trying increases the memory for Eclipse itself. To increase the memory for an application you're running in Eclipse to 1536m follow these steps:

1. Go to **Run > Run Configurations...**
2. Select your **Java Application**
3. Go to the **Arguments** tab
4. Add `-Xmx1536m` to the your **VM arguments**

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to increase heap size allocated by the JVM in eclipse directly In eclipse IDE goto

```
Run---->Run Configurations---->
```

Enter

```
-Xmx1g
```

(It is used to set the max size like Xmx256m or Xmx1g...... m-->mb g--->gb)